# Using a ListView to lay out a list of checkboxes and text

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I need to create a layout with a list of checkboxes on the left and text on the right. However, I need them to be laid out in a very specific way. I've searched for such a layout in many places, but no success (the closest I got to what I want was [this](http://blog.maxaller.name/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/listview_footer_scrolling.png).

[This is the layout I need for my list](http://i43.tinypic.com/mme9hi.jpg)

Can I achieve this with a `ListView`?

Comment: Should work. But you will have to create some graphics to make it look like the picture.

Comment: The android plugin for Eclipse makes it really easy to play with and tweak layouts. Try it out yourself and then come back if you have a more specific problem. A ListView sounds like a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using ListView easily.
You should create your own Adapter and override your getView there 
and return a RelativeLayout with your components inside e.g. a Button and a TextView
and set this adapter into your ListView.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still wasn't able to implement the up and down arrow buttons, but I guess that's ok.

Comment: Check the RelativeLayout's LayoutParams.         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW (or LEFT_OF or RIGHT_OF depends on your layout)), butView); it depends on what you want. the RelativeLayout gives you a flexibility to align views within itself with appropriate parameters. You will have to add it in order buttonUP,textview (RIGHT_OF,buttonUPid) and buttonDOWN(BELOW,buttonUPid). Just giving you the idea.

Comment: I did it the way you recommended. But see it, the `getView` method is called for every row. So I don't think I can change the scroll using this method.

Comment: Ahhh you want to change the scroll's buttons' looks. Okay. I might have an advice for that too. Use the style on your ListView. The style is described in the res/values/styles.xml usually. There you can play with background images,fonts and all the good stuff for certain Views. I haven't changed the looks of the ListViews but I've played with Dialog's styles indeed. Hope it helps mate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't test this right now, but when I do this I'll post the results here.

Comment: Well, I searched for styles.xml but it's not there. I've searched google for some custom scrollbars but it seems that it's not very common to change it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html and this one http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/values/styles.html not sure if this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own layout for each item in `ListView` and `ListAdapter` for your ListView

Check this link http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html

Hope this helps you